# Memory profiling tools

Tags: memory-management

Hi
I am trying to find a memory leak issue at a client site. They are using our application and over time while using it the application runs out of memory and throw an OutOfMemory exception. It would not be easy to replicate the issue inhouse since we will have to sit for hours to replicate their workflow. So I need to put a tool (possibly free) on their machine which should be able to tell me how the memory is being uesd by the application and some generation infor. So doen anybody know of a tool that can achieve this or can anybody point me in a direction that can help me find the problem without profiling the whole application in dev env

Comment: what language is the application?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Java, you can set the `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` flag, which will cause the JVM to dump the heap when it throws out of memory exceptions. Then, you can take the dump and run it through jhat to see where the memory is being allocated. (There's also an Eclipse based heap dump analysis tool.) I've used this in the past with great success.

Comment: sorry i should have mentioned, its a .net 3.5 application

Answer (score 0):

It so happens that the new CLR Profiler with support for .NET 2.0 through 4.0 was just released by Microsoft:

[David Broman's CLR Profiling API Blog: CLRProfiler V4 Released](https://web.archive.org/web/20190114032249/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davbr/2011/02/01/clrprofiler-v4-released)

It's free.